# Loop and Compare through localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have personal project with API calls. When I'm making HTTP requests (searching) items are displayed on Key press on the page, items can be bookmarked which means I can click on single item and save it to local storage. When input is empty I show to user bookmarked items. Now I want to show to user when he starts to search again if the some of results are saved by adding class "bookmarked" which darkens result div. SO My question is how do I loop and compare search result to local storage items in a efficient way.

I've tried this but doesn't seem to be very good.

```
$('.bookmakrk').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.item);
})

    $('.bookmakrk').click(function(){
  localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.item);
})

http.done(function(data){
  var x = data.data;
  for(var key in x){
    if(localStorage.key(key)){
     $( "body" ).appen("<div class='bookmarked'>");
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I wouldn't save every bookmark in a seperate localStorage item. I would create an array which you write to localStorage with JSON.stringify. This way you can read it out of local storage at page load, use the javascript array for comparison and adding new bookmarks - and everytime something changes write back the whole array to local storage.

Comment: Are `'.bookmakrk'` and `'bookmarked'` intended to be the same `className`?

Comment: no no bookmark is button and the other one is div that wraps item.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't save every bookmark in a seperate localStorage item. I would create an array which you write to localStorage with JSON.stringify. This way you can read it out of local storage at page load, use the javascript array for comparison and adding new bookmarks - and everytime something changes write back the whole array to local storage.

Like this:

```
var bookmarks = [];
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") !== null){
       bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
    }
});

http.done(function(data){
  var x = data.data;
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    if(bookmarks.indexOf(x[i]) >= 0){
     // do stuff
    }
  }
})

function addBoomark(item){
    // push item to bookmarks array
    bookmarks.push(item);
    // save bookmarks array to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
}

function removeBookmark(itemId){
    // use filter to get all items which don't match to the itemId you want to remove
    bookmarks = bookmarks.filter(function(item){return item.id !== itemId});
    // save bookmarks array to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
}
```